# How can I solve this "Error in parse" in R markdown?

Tags: r, markdown

I am new to R programming. I have tried to knit a R markdown but the following error appears :
Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src) : :12:1: unexpected symbol 11:12 head ^ Calls:  ...  -> parse_all -> parse_all.character -> parse

[Error in R markdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ah9IN.png)

What should I do ?

Many thanks in advance for your help !

Charlotte

Comment: This error always indicates syntax errors. RStudio is even highlighting where they are. Looks like a missing parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

In line 80 you only close the parenthesis of the vector, but you also have to close the parenthesis of the function `setnames`